# Pandas group by then apply throwing a warning

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

I have the lines of code

```
df = df.groupby(by=['col_A','col_B'])['float_col_c']
df.loc[:,'amount_cumulative'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())
```

Which throws the warning:

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:362: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[key] = _infer_fill_value(value)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:543: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
```

Normally when I see that error I'm able to change something to `.loc[]` to fix it, but in this case the warning seems to refer to another issue. I know that I can just suppress the warning but I'd rather understand the issue I'm making with Pandas syntax. Any suggestions are much appreciated on how to correct this syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely that your `df` is already a copy of another dataframe. And your naming `df_rev_melt_trim` also suggests that. Test

```
old_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(1,10,1000),
                   'B':np.random.randint(1,10,1000),
                   'C':np.random.uniform(0,1,1000)})

df = old_df[old_df['A'] > 5]

df['amount_cumulative'] = df.groupby(by=['A','B'])['C'].cumsum()
```

yields the same warning. Instead, you can do:

```
old_df.loc[df.index,'amount_cumulative'] = df.groupby(by=['A','B'])['C'].cumsum()
```

and no warning shows.

Answer (score 2):

<del>I belive it is because of the `.loc[:, 'amount_cumulative']` indexing, which returns a slice of `df`, not a reference to a new column</del>

**Update:** `df` was a copy itself as @QuangHoang correctly pointed out, in which case the following will still throw an error.

You can have the expected result without warning with something as simple as this:

```py
df['amount_cumulative'] = df.groupby(['col_A','col_B'])['float_col_c'].cumsum()
```

Comment: This shortened the warning but it's still throwing: `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df_rev_melt_trim['amount_cumulative'] = df_rev_melt_trim.groupby(by=['company_id','revenue_type'])['amount_usd'].cumsum()`